# Remove duplicate attributes CSS

Tags: css

I have a list of attributes

```css
#tns1 > .tns-item {
    width: calc(5.9% - 6px);
}

#tns2 > .tns-item {
    width: calc(5.9% - 6px);
}

#tns3 > .tns-item {
    width: calc(5.9% - 6px);
}

#tns4 > .tns-item {
    width: calc(5.9% - 6px);
}

#tns5 > .tns-item {
    width: calc(5.9% - 6px);
}

#tns6 > .tns-item {
    width: calc(5.9% - 6px);
}

#tns7 > .tns-item {
    width: calc(5.9% - 6px);
}
```

How can I replace it with something similar so that it doesn't happen again.

```css
#tns[n] > .tns-item {
    width: calc(5.9% - 6px);
}
```

where n is any number?

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try to

```css
[id^="tn"] > .tns-item {
    width: calc(5.9% - 6px);
}
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#attrvalue_4

> `[attr^=value]`

> Represents elements with an attribute name of attr whose value is prefixed (preceded) by value.

---

or

---

If the specifity is not high enough, then you may also try

```css
:is(#tns1 ,#tns2 ,#tns3,#tns4 ,#tns5 ,#tns6,#tns7) > .tns-item {
    width: calc(5.9% - 6px);
}
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is